# Pros and Cons of using Own Selectors in selenium

Tags: selenium, selector

I would like to implement my Own `By` Class in order to have custom selectors. What are the pros and cons of using Custom Selectors

DEV code

```
<button class="btn js-AddNuts" type="button" testid="addbutton">
```

Here Selector is `testid`

Reason: We are planning to have test specific selectors and design Names for all the elements in DEV Code so that if they change anything in DEV it doesn't impact test.

Comment: Why are you going to create your own custom selector while it could be simply find `By.cssSelector`, `By.xpath` etc....??? elaborate your purpose...

Comment: question updated with reason

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a custom locator in this case (or any case that I have run across or can think of). You can simply use the following code that uses a CSS Selector.

```
By.cssSelector("button[testid='addbutton']")
```

I would suggest that you spend some time reading and learning CSS Selectors. They are very powerful.

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

Comment: As I already asked, OP interested to create own custom selector.. Thanks

Comment: And could you give the reason of down vote for my answer...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur No, what OP asked is, "What are the pros and cons of using Custom Selectors." The main CON is there is no need. There are no PROS that I can think of to creating a brand new locator that is going to do what other selectors already do. You listed no PRO to creating a custom locator in your answer, you just provided how to do so.

Comment: Why there is no need for custom selector...if no need why selenium provides us to create custom locator...?? Why selenium itself provides different types of locator??... According to OP, he wants to create custom locator to make life easier by their for those who does not know how to create xPath or cssSelector...It is much beneficial for those...they just simply create custom by object as we create for ID if we could simply identify it by I'd...why do you recommend you to all use By.id locator if you could simply identify by.Id..???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I said, "There is no need to create a custom locator in this case." not that there is never a need. I can't think of a need and I have been doing this for a while and never run into a case where existing locators can't do what is needed. Just because it's available doesn't mean it's good practice to create a new locator for everything. Yes, you can do it but why would you? What's the benefit?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur OP never said anything about making life easier for those who do not know XPath or CSS selectors. I'm not sure where you got that from. If they can't understand CSS Selectors, I'm not sure how they are going to understand how to program scripts since it's way more complicated.

Comment: did you understand OP's purpose..why he ask this question.. I think He just want to create their own automation tools over selenium where he makes as simple as possible...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur the purpose of the question was to know the pros and cons of creating a custom locator. That's what OP asked. All this other stuff that you are interpreting is just a guess on your part because it's not in the question. You keep saying simple... I don't think you understand what that word means.

Comment: I clearly understand. You are not understanding.. anyway thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

As you know there is no problem with creating your own locator, Selenium provides the functionality to create custom locator. Basically selenium internally uses to locate element using `xPath` when you are going to find element [`By.id`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-common/0.9.7089/org/openqa/selenium/By.java#By.id%28java.lang.String%29), [`By.name`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-common/0.9.7089/org/openqa/selenium/By.java#By.name%28java.lang.String%29) etc. So you could create simply your own locator by extending `By` class.

If you want to create a custom locator which locate element using `testid`, you should create as below (Assuming you are using java) :-

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

class ByTestId extends By {

    private final String testId;

    public ByTestId(String testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
        return context.findElements(By
                .xpath(".//*[@testid = '"+testId+"']"));
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement(SearchContext context) {
        return context.findElement(By
                .xpath("//*[@testid = '"+testId+"']"));
    }
}
```

Now you can easily locate element by using `testid` as below :-

```
//for single webelement
WebElement element = driver.findElement(new ByTestId("addbutton"));

//for list of webelements
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(new ByTestId("addbutton"));
```

**Note** : You can also locate the element in your custom `By` class using `By.cssSelector` as : `By.cssSelector("*[testid = '"+testId+"']")`

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Selenium doesn't use an XPath internally to find an element By.id, By.name`. Moreover you shouldn't recommend an XPath when it's possible with a CSS selector. Note that you also forgot to answer the question.

Comment: @FlorentB. yeah off course we can use `By.cssSelector` here but in this context it just point to single attribute so if we use `By.xpath` I think no problem with this at all. And as you seeing in this link http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-common/0.9.7089/org/openqa/selenium/By.java#By.id%28java.lang.String%29... it's clearly goes to find element using xpath in else condition..

Comment: Even if it points to a single attribute, you should recommend a CSS selector since it is less expensive. And no, Selenium doesn't use an XPath to find an element By.id. The else condition you are referring is a fallback for the drivers not supporting the location by id. The Java client is the only one implementing it and I don't know any driver meeting this condition. Note that your XPath is also incorrect, it should be relative to the context and not the page (`.//` instead of `//`).

Comment: @FlorentB I really appreciate your point.. and I already updated answer to locate element using cssSelector.. thanks for pointing me...but I didn't understand why provided xpath is incorrect... could you please give me some scenarios HTML where it could be incorrect...:)

Comment: @JeffC please leave the reason for down vote as well..:)

Comment: Because it's not correct for a couple reasons as Florent already pointed out. Also, there is no PRO to creating a custom locator here.

Comment: @JeffC Here by creating custom locator user can simply identify to choose different different locator..It will beneficial for those user who does not know how to create xPath or cssSelector, they can simply call By custom locator. as OP wants..If there is no PRO why selenium provides different types of locator us to locate element to make life easier... please explain

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, your XPath is incorrect because `context.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@testid='foo']"))` will search in the whole page. To search only within the descendants of `context`, you need to add a dot in front: `context.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@testid='foo']"))`.

Comment: You don't need to be a CSS Selector expert to fill in the template "<html element>[testid='<testid>']". Creating a whole other locator accomplishes nothing to simplify the process. In fact it creates a whole other source for potential bugs. What if testid is not unique on the page? Then the locator you used won't work. There's also no way to specify the element that the testid attribute is on. Too many people try to overcomplicate the simplest things... this is one such example. There is no good reason to do this. It makes nothing simpler.

Comment: You've taken a one liner, `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[testid='addbutton']"));`, and turned it into a one liner (after adding 20 lines of code for the new locator), `driver.findElement(new ByTestId("addbutton"));`, that is more restrictive. How does this improve anything?

Comment: @JeffC Do you know when you call `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[testid='addbutton']"));` how many lines call behind this...??? It also call with multiple lines...it's almost similar to `driver.findElement(new ByTestId("addbutton"));`....And one benefit here it makes easy life if I doesn't know about xPath or cssSelector...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I don't know how many lines of code are behind a simple `.findElement()` call by CSS selector but I do know that there are 20 more than that behind your custom locator code. So... why do it? You keep saying it makes life easy but I just said you had to add 20 lines of custom code that you will potentially find bugs with, the way you implemented it is more restrictive, and you still haven't reduced the number of lines of code to call it... it's still one. You and I apparently have a very different definition of what makes life easier.

Comment: @JeffC omg how can you say it's add 20 more lines of code. Custom selector works same as already created locator.. Please review selenium code first then give answer...:)

Comment: Did you read your own answer? Count the lines of code in your answer that gets added to the existing code that is in Selenium. That's where I get 20.

Comment: @JeffC why are not understanding it just works as other locators.  It's implementation same after extending By to the locator object... please go to selenium code and understand...I'm just creating new By locator...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur This is my last comment... if you add your newly implemented locator and then call it, the code execution will go through the custom code you implemented then through the standard Selenium code to find the element. I would suggest that you put your code in a project and then call it and step through it with the debugger then you will better understand. You have added 20 lines of code to do something that can already be done. You have introduced extra complexity for no reason. Go back and reread my comments and my answer... I can't help you understand any more than that.

Comment: @JeffC did you debug??.. firstly you go to debug and let me know how many lines covered by debugger during locating an element by custom locator and other locators...:)

Comment: @FlorentB. You are right...but if it's a generic locator like others then I think it will necessary to search for whole page rather than only descendant...what do you suggest??..

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, it doesn't make sense to search the whole page from an element. For instance `driver.findElement(by.Id('foo1')).findElement(new ByTestId("foo2"));` means that you want `foo2` which is inside `foo1`. If you were to search "foo2" in the whole page then you would simply call `driver.findElement(new ByTestId("foo2"));`. You probably missed the fact that the context is either the driver or an element.

Comment: @FlorentB. Amazing...I never thought about this... thanks to point it out... updated the answer...:)